# Translating C flexible array members with length fields to Ada

Tags: ada

While writing bindings for interfacing with C code, I am finding issues translating the numerous instances of structs with flexible array members to Ada, as such

```c
struct example {
    size_t length;
    int    body[];
};
```

I've been told for Ada that behaviors like that can be replicated with discriminated types, but I cannot find a way to use the `length` field as a discriminant, while maintaining the layout of the structure so that the records can be used to interface with the C code, something like

```
type Example (Count : Integer := Length) is record
   Length : Unsigned_64;
   Body   : Integer (1 .. Count);
end record;
```

Is there any way to create a type like that with that array? I've been defaulting for now to grabbing the address of that location and declaring the array myself on place for use, is there any better way? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The discriminant is itself a component of the record, and has to be stored somewhere.

This code,

```ada
type Integer_Array is array (Natural range <>) of Integer;

type Example (Count : Natural) is record
   Bdy : Integer_Array (1 .. Count);
end record;
```

compiled with `-gnatR` to show representtion information, says

```
for Integer_Array'Alignment use 4;
for Integer_Array'Component_Size use 32;

for Example'Object_Size use 68719476736;
for Example'Value_Size use ??;
for Example'Alignment use 4;
for Example use record
   Count at 0 range  0 .. 31;
   Bdy   at 4 range  0 .. ??;
end record;
```

so we can see that GNAT has decided to put `Count` in the first 4 bytes, just like the C (well, this is a common C idiom, so I suppose it’s defined behaviour for C struct components to be allocated in source order).

Since this is to be used for interfacing with C, we could say so,

```ada
type Example (Count : Natural) is record
   Bdy : Integer_Array (1 .. Count);
end record
  with Convention => C;
```

but as [Niklas points out](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70483139/40851) the compiler is doubtful about this (it’s warning you that the Standard doesn’t specify the meaning of the construct).

We could confirm at least that we want `Count` to be in the first 4 bytes, adding

```ada
for Example use record
   Count at 0 range 0 .. 31;
end record;
```

but I don’t suppose that would stop a different compiler using a different scheme (e.g. two structures, the first containing `Count` and the address of the second, `Bdy`).

Answer (score 6):

Here is an example in which Ada code calls C code, passing objects of this kind from Ada to C and from C to Ada. The C header is c_example.h:

```
typedef struct {
    size_t length;
    int    body[];
} example_t;

extern void example_print (example_t *e /* in */);
// Print the contents of e.

extern example_t * example_get (void);
// Return a pointer to an example_t that remains owned
// by the C part (that is, the caller can use it, but should
// not attempt to deallocate it).
```

The C code is c_example.c:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "c_example.h"

void example_print (example_t *e /* in */)
{
   printf ("C example: length = %zd\n", e->length);

   for (int i = 0; i < e->length; i++)
   {
      printf ("body[ %d ] = %d\n", i, e->body[i]);
   }
}  // example_print

static example_t datum = {4,{6,7,8,9}};

example_t * example_get (void)
{
   return &datum;
}  // example_get
```

The C-to-Ada binding is defined in c_binding.ads:

```
with Interfaces.C;

package C_Binding
is
   pragma Linker_Options ("c_example.o");
   use Interfaces.C;

   type Int_Array is array (size_t range <>) of int
      with Convention => C;

   type Example_t (Length : size_t) is record
      Bod : Int_Array(1 .. Length);
   end record
      with Convention => C;

   type Example_ptr is access all Example_t
      with Convention => C;

   procedure Print (e : in Example_t)
      with Import, Convention => C, External_Name => "example_print";

   function Get return Example_Ptr
      with Import, Convention => C, External_Name => "example_get";

end C_Binding;
```

The test main program is flexarr.adb:

```
with Ada.Text_IO;
with C_Binding;

procedure FlexArr
is

   for_c : constant C_Binding.Example_t :=
      (Length => 5, Bod => (55, 66, 77, 88, 99));

   from_c : C_Binding.Example_ptr;

begin

   C_Binding.Print (for_c);

   from_c := C_Binding.Get;

   Ada.Text_IO.Put_Line (
      "Ada example: length =" & from_c.Length'Image);

   for I in 1 .. from_c.Length loop
      Ada.Text_IO.Put_Line (
         "body[" & I'Image & " ] =" & from_c.Bod(I)'Image);
   end loop;

end FlexArr;
```

I build the program thusly:

```
gcc -c -Wall c_example.c
gnatmake -Wall flexarr.adb
```

And this is the output from ./flexarr:

```
C example: length = 5
body[ 0 ] = 55
body[ 1 ] = 66
body[ 2 ] = 77
body[ 3 ] = 88
body[ 4 ] = 99
Ada example: length = 4
body[ 1 ] = 6
body[ 2 ] = 7
body[ 3 ] = 8
body[ 4 ] = 9
```

So it seems to work. However, the Ada compiler (gnat) gives me some warnings from the C_Binding package:

```
c_binding.ads:14:12: warning: discriminated record has no direct equivalent in C
c_binding.ads:14:12: warning: use of convention for type "Example_t" is dubious
```

This means that while this interfacing method works with gnat, it might not work with other compilers, for example Ada compilers that allocate the Bod component array separately from the fixed-size part of the record (whether such a compiler would accept Convention => C for this record type is questionable).

To make the interface more portable, make the following changes. In C_Binding, change Length from a discriminant to an ordinary component and make Bod a fixed-size array, using some maximum size, here 1000 elements as an example:

```
   type Int_Array is array (size_t range 1 .. 1_000) of int
      with Convention => C;

   type Example_t is record
      Length : size_t;
      Bod    : Int_Array;
   end record
      with Convention => C;
```

In the test main program, change the declaration of for_c to pad the array with zeros:

```
   for_c : constant C_Binding.Example_t :=
      (Length => 5, Bod => (55, 66, 77, 88, 99, others => 0));
```

For speed, you could instead let the unused part of the array be uninitialized: "others => <>".

If you cannot find a reasonably small maximum size, it should be possible to define the C binding to be generic in the actual size. But that is getting rather messy.

Note that if all the record/struct objects are created on the C side, and the Ada side only reads and writes them, then the maximum size defined in the binding is used only for index bounds checking and can be very large without impact on the memory usage.

In this example I made the Ada side start indexing from 1, but you can change it to start from zero if you want to make it more similar to the C code.

Finally, in the non-discriminated case, I recommend making Example_t a "limited" type ("type Example_t is limited record ...") so that you cannot assign whole values of that type, nor compare them. The reason is that when the C side provides an Example_t object to the Ada side, the actual size of the object may be smaller than the maximum size defined on the Ada side, but an Ada assignment or comparison would try to use the maximum size, which could make the program read or write memory that should not be read or written.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but the layout of the struct and translated record are mandated by a protocol that I cannot change, the goal was some kind of expression to help using the record field 'length' as the discriminant to clean the code up, thus, I cannot accept this answer. I will edit the question to point out this fact

Comment: Your question is still not clear on what you want to do. You say "translate into Ada code", but it seems you want to interface Ada code to C code in some way. Please explain more clearly how that interfacing takes place. Is the structure a parameter to an inter-language call? If the question is only on whether the discriminant is the max index or the length, I see no reason why the Ada code could not let the indices start from 1, in which case a "Length" discriminant can be used.

Comment: Thanks for the insight, I corrected the question, I hope the underlying intention is clearer now

Answer (score 2):

C array indices always start at 0.
If you want to duplicate the C structure remember that the discriminant is a member of the record.

```
type Example (Length : Integer) is record
   body : array(0 .. Length - 1) of Integer;
end record;
```

Comment: That example will not work, for three reasons: first, "body" is a reserved word, and cannot be used as the identifier of a record component; second, a record component cannot be of an anonymous array type, but must instead use an array type declared separately; third, when a discriminant is used to constrain a component, you are not allowed to add or subtract anything from the discriminant, but must use the discriminant as such. I'll post a corrected example as a separate answer since it will not fit in a comment.